# iOS Network extension NETunnelProviderManager startVPNTunnel not throw error

Tags: ios, vpn

I am developing an private VPN,but it does not work.

```
currentVPNManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil{
                        }
                        else{
                            currentVPNManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                                if error != nil{
                                }
                                else{
                                    do{
                                        try currentVPNManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
                                    }
                                    catch{
                                        print(error)

                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
```

startVPNtunnel did not throw any error?

Comment: have you check are your servers working? You should add configuration directly to iOS settings and check that it has to connect to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable `Personal VPN` from **Capabilities** and try loading all preferences, then save and finally start VPN tunnel in order. You can find sample below.

```
let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared()
```

Using vpnManager

```
vpnManager.loadFromPreferences { error in
        if let error = error {
            NSLog("NEVPNManager error on loading all preferences \(error)")
            return
        }
        self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("NEVPNManager error on save to preferences \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
            } catch (let error) {
                NSLog("NEVPNManager error on save to preferences \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
```